# AWS OpenSearch - this action would add [10] total shards, but this cluster currently has [3996]/[4000] maximum shards open

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-opensearch

I have an `OpenSearch` cluster on `AWS` and it has some data. The data are ingested from the `Kinesis Firehose`, but I am getting the following error:

> {"attemptsMade":8,"arrivalTimestamp":1660873371793,"errorCode":"400","errorMessage":"{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Validation Failed: 1: this action would add [10] total shards, but this cluster currently has [3996]/[4000] maximum shards open;"}"

And I have 4 node cluster, and when I try to get the number of shards allocated for each node as below:

```
  shards disk.indices disk.used disk.avail disk.total         
   983       89.8gb   115.1gb    376.8gb      492gb           
   983       91.2gb   116.5gb    375.4gb      492gb           
   983       89.1gb   114.5gb    377.5gb      492gb           
   983       90.6gb   115.9gb      376gb      492gb
```

In above, what does the `shards` column mean? Is that the total number (max) of shards that node can accomodate?

And then I tried to get all the indices with their shards, PS: in below, I haven't added all the indices as there are over 3000+ indices, so here's a few of them:

```
GET _cat/shards?v


index                                                      shard prirep state      docs    store           
mc-2022-08-07                                              4     p      STARTED      23  182.5kb 
mc-2022-08-07                                              4     r      STARTED      23  182.5kb 
mc-2022-08-07                                              2     r      STARTED      13  217.6kb 
mc-2022-08-07                                              3     p      STARTED       9  192.9kb 
mc-2022-08-07                                              1     p      STARTED      10    193kb 
mc-2022-08-07                                              0     p      STARTED      13   71.3kb 
. . .
```

And I tried to add all the values in the above output's `shard` column and I ended up getting the value `7506`

But according to the error message above, it can't go over 4000 but it already has the value `7506`

Can someone help me understand what is happening here?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The first output shows that each of your nodes has 983 shards. It seems that you're trying to add another index with 5 primary shards + one replica for each, which means 10 additional shards.

There's a [cluster-wide setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cluster.html#cluster-shard-limit) called `cluster.max_shards_per_node` that prevents having more than 1000 shards per node, in your case 4 x 1000 = 4000. This is of course a default value that can be changed and simply acts as a safety net to not overload the cluster.

The command to lift that limit is this one:

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster.max_shards_per_node": 1100
  }
}
```

HOWEVER, looking at your second output, we can draw a few points:

- you have too many shards
- and probably each of your shards are too small a shard is supposed to contain up to [10-50 GB of data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/size-your-shards.html#shard-size-recommendation), but in your case we're down to a few KB

We don't see the full output of `_cat/shards` but depending on your workload, each of your index would probably be fine with a single primary shard. You can specify that at index creation time or in an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html) where you define the default mappings and settings for your index.

Another point regarding the output of `_cat/shards`, the number you see in the shards column is NOT a number of shards, but the id of the shard. If your index has 5 primary shards + one replica, you'll get

- primary shard 0
- replica shard 0
- primary shard 1
- replica shard 1
- primary shard 2
- replica shard 2
- primary shard 3
- replica shard 3
- primary shard 4
- replica shard 4

If you count the number of lines in the `_cat/shards` output, however, you'll get 3996 lines.

In summary, I would strongly suggest that you implement [Index Lifecycle Management (ILM)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html) or since you're on Opensearch, the feature is called [Index State Management (ISM)](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/im-plugin/ism/index/) in order to only create a new index when absolutely necessary.

Also I would advise to [reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) small daily indices together into bigger indices (weekly, monthly, etc)